# How to find number of database round trips by an application

Tags: java, oracle, profiling

I am a java programmer and I want to know how many database calls/trips are done by my application. We use Oracle as our relational database.
With oracle, I got to know about a way to alter session statistics and generate the trace files. Below are the queries to be fired:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMED_STATISTICS = TRUE;

 ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;
```

After the trace files are generated, they could be read using the TKProf utility. But this approach cannot be used because:

1. my application uses hibernate and spring frameworks and hence the application does not have an handle to the session.
2. Even if we get the trace files, I need to know whether the set of queries are fired in one go (in a batch) or separately. I am not sure if TkProf output could help to understand this.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: I'd be surprised if Hibernate didn't have an option for logging all the SQL calls it made.

Comment: Indeed googling "hibernate log sql" will give you a number of pages that describe how to switch it on, but I guess your actual answer also depends on which version of Hibernate you're using.

Comment: I know that Hibernate has an option of logging SQL queries it fired :) and I have already tried that. But this will not resolve my concern to know if the queries were fired in a batch or individually.

Comment: @Amit just mention the actual problem you are trying to solve in your question--you will save other peoples time and get better responses. so, you would like to figure out is several insert/update statements are executed as a batch or individually?

Comment: For problem (1) you could use a logon trigger to turn on session-level tracing, restricted to only the user ID you use to connect from Java if you want. Alternatively you can turn this on at database level instead of at session level. Either can produce a large volume of trace files.

Comment: @Markus - Sorry for the confusion. It was not intended. My goal is to figure out the number of round trips made by my application to the database server. Also while have a look at the round trips I want to know what queries were information (queries) were sent by the application to the db server which would help me to understand if the queries are executed in a batch.

Answer (score 3):

In TkProf, you can basically tell the number of round-trips as the number of "calls" (although there are exceptions so that less round trips are required, e.g. parse/execute/fetch of a single row select is, theoretically, possible in a single round trip, the so called "exact fetch" feature of oracle). However as a estimate, the tkprof figures are good enough.

If trace wait events, you should directly see the 'SQL*Net from/to client' wait events in the raw trace, but I think tkprof does not show it (not sure, give it a try).

Another way is to look into the session statistics:

```
select value
  from v$mystat ms, v$statname sn
 where ms.value > 0
   and ms.statistic#=sn.statistic#
   and sn.name IN ('SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client')
```

However, if you do that in your app, you will slowdown your app, and the figures you receive will include the round-trips for that select.

A wrote a few articles about round-trip optimization:

- http://blog.fatalmind.com/2009/12/22/latency-security-vs-performance/
- http://blog.fatalmind.com/2010/01/29/oracle-jdbc-prefetch-portability/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but as I already mentioned to get the trace files which can be viewed through TkProf I would have fire additional queries on the session to which I do not have an handle.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use a dedicated database (or timeframe) for this test, so it doesn't get easily confused with other sessions.

Secondly, look at the view v$session to identify the session(s) for hibernate. The USERNAME, OSUSER, TERMINAL, MACHINE should make this obvious. The SID and SERIAL# columns uniquely identify the session. Actually the SID is unique at any time. The SERIAL# is only needed if you have sessions disconnecting and reconnecting.

Thirdly, use v$sessstat (filtered on the SID,SERIAL# from the v$session) and v$statname (as shown by Markus) to pull out the number of round trips. You can take a snapshot before the test, run the test, then look at the values again and determine the work done.

That said, I'm not sure it is a particularly useful measure in itself. The TKPROF will be more detailed and is much more focussed on time (which is a more useful measure).

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to get a dedicated event 10046 level 12 tracefile of the running session. You will find there all information in detail. This means that you can see how many fetches the application will do per executed command and the related wait events/elapsed time. The resul can be analyzed using tool from Oracle like TKPROF or Oracle Trace Analyzer or Third party tools like [QueryAdvisor][1].

By the way you can ask your DBA to define a database trigger activating Oracle filetrace automatic after login. So capturing the file should not be the problem.

R.U.

[1]: http://www.queryadvisor.com/"TKPROF Oracle tracefile analysis with QueryAdvisor"